# Is there any way to loop through my sql results and store certain name/value pairs elsewhere in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, list, webmatrix

I have a large result set coming from a pretty complex SQL query. Among the values are a `string` which represents a location (that will later help me determine the page location that the value came from), an `int` which is a priority number calculated for each row based on other values from the row, and another `string` which contains a value I must remember for display later.

The problem is that the sql query is so complex (it has UNIONS, JOINS, and complex calculations with aliases) that I can't logically fit anything else into it without messing with the way it works.

Suffice it to say, though, after the query is done and the calculations performed, I need something that perhaps aggregate functions might solve, but that IS NOT an option, as all the columns do not come from other aggregate functions.

I have been wracking my brain for days now as to how I can iterate through the results, store a pair of values in a list (or two separate lists tied together somehow) where one value is the sum of all the priority values for each location and the other value is a distinct location value (i.e., as the results are looped through, it will not create another list item with the same location value that has been used before, HOWEVER, it does still need the sum of all of the other priority values from locations that ARE identical). Also, the results need to be ordered by priority in Descending order (hence the problem with using two lists).

**EXAMPLE:**

**EDIT:** I forgot, the preserved value should be the value from the row with the highest priority from the sql query.

If I had the following results:

```
  location                      priority                               value  

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   page1                           1                                  some text!
   page2                           3                                  more text!
   page2                           4                               even more text!
   page3                           3                                  text again
   page3                           1                                     text
   page3                           1                              still more text!
   page4                           6                                     text
```

If I was able to do what I wanted I would be able to achieve something like this after iteration (and in this order):

```
  location                      priority                               value  

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   page2                           7                               even more text!
   page4                           6                                    text
   page3                           5                                  text again
   page1                           1                                  some text!
```

I have done research after research after research but absolutely nothing really even gets close to solving this dilemma.

Is what I'm asking too tough for even the powerful C# language?

**THINGS I HAVE CONSIDERED:**

*Looping through the sql results and checking each location for repeats, adding together all priority values as I go, and storing these two plus value in two or three separate lists.*

**Why I still need help**

I can't use a foreach because the logic didn't pan out, and I can't use a `for` loop because I can't access an IEnumerable (or whatever type it is that stores what's returned from `Database.Open.Query()` by index. (this makes sense, of course). Also, I need to sort on priority, but can't get one list out of sync with the others.

---

*Using LINQ to select and store what I need*

**Why I still need help**

I don't know LINQ (at all!) mainly because I don't understand lambda expressions (no matter HOW MUCH I read up about it).

---

*Using an instantiated class to store the name/value pairs*

**Why I still need help**

Not only do I expect sorting on this sort of thing to be impossible, and while I do now how to use `.cs` files in my C#.net webpages with WebMatrix environment, I have mainly only ever used static classes and would also need a little refresher course on constructors and how to set this up appropriately.

---

*Somehow fitting this functionality into the already sizeable and complex SQL query*

**Why I still need help**

While this is probably where I would ideally like this functionality to be, I stress again that this IS NOT AN OPTION. I have tried using aggregate functions, but only get an error saying how not all the other columns come from aggregate functions.

---

*Making another query based on values from the first query's result set*

**Why I still need help**

I can't select distinct results based on only one column (i.e., location) alone.

---

*Assuming I could get the loop logic correct, storing the values in a 3 dimensional array*

**Why I still need help**

I can't declare the array, because I do not know all of its dimensions before I need to use it.

Comment: Are you storing the results of this query in an ADO.NET dataset, Entity Framework entity, or what?

Comment: @Cortright it would be like this `var results = Database.Open("databaseName").Query(queryString, argumentArray)` According to MSDN the data type is: `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Object>`

Comment: I knew I've seen it before. [CabalTherapy](http://vrtstore.com/pic/JUD/Cabal%20Therapy.full.jpg).. Too bad it does not have any flavor text. That reminds me of an [EssenceLeak](http://8e8460c4912582c4e519-11fcbfd88ed5b90cfb46edba899033c9.r65.cf1.rackcdn.com/sales/cardscans/MTG/INV/en/nonfoil/EssenceLeak.jpg) with its inspiring footnote. I think I still have it somewhere in my wallet heh.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl LOL, good catch! I wondered how long it would be till someone noticed that picture. Good old card from the days of old extended (back when Trinity Green or Tinker could be played). Your name reminds me of Final Fantasy 8, actually, imagine that :)

Comment: @VoidKing: actually, FF7, but shhh! ;)

Comment: @quetzalcoatl No, I was thinking of FF8 (I'm not shhhing very well am I?), Quezacotl (if I spelled that right) was the thunder bird aeon.

Comment: I know what you meant ;) But, in turn, I meant that on my side "Quetzalcoatl" got its origin from FF7. Actually, neither of them got him properly. Quetzalcoatl stands for a "feathered snake", an Aztek god of wind and knowledge [->wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quetzalcoatl).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your post has amazed me in a number of ways like saying to 'mostly using static classes' and 'expecting instantiate a class/object to be impossible'.. really strange things you say. I can only respond in a quote from Charles Babbage:

> I am not able rightly to apprehend the kind of confusion of ideas that could provoke such a question.

Anyways.. As you say you find lambdas hard, let's trace the problem in the classic 'manual' way.

Let's assume you have a list of ROWS that contains LOCATIONS and PRIORITIES.

```
List<DataRow> rows = .... ; // datatable, sqldatareader, whatever
```

You say you need:

- list of unique locations
- a "list" of locations paired up with summed up priorites

Let's start with the first objective.

To gather a list of unique 'values', a HashSet is just perfect:

```
HashSet<string> locations = new HashSet<string>();
foreach(var row in rows)
    locations.Add( (string)rows["LOCATION"] );
```

well, and that's all. After that, the `locations` hashset will only remember all the unique locations. The "Add" does not result in duplicate elements. The HashSet checks and "uniquifies" all values that are put inside it. Small tricky thing is the hashset does not have the `[index]` operator. You'll have to enumerate the hashset to get the values:

```
foreach(string loc in locations)
{
    Console.WriteLine(loc);
}
```

or convert/rewrite it to a list:

```
List<string> locList = new List<string>(locations);
Console.WriteLine(locList[2]); // of course, assuming there were at least three..
```

Let's get to the second objective.

To gather a list of values related to some thing behaving like a "logical key", a `Dictionary<Key,Val>` may be useful. It allows you to store/associate a "value" with some "key", ie:

```
Dictionary<string, double> dict = new Dictionary<string, double>();
dict["mamma"] = 123.45;
double d = dict["mamma"]; // d == 123.45
```

dict["mamma"] += 101; // possible!
    double e = dict["mamma"]; // d == 224.45

However, it has a behavior of happily **throwing** exceptions when you try to **read** from an **unknown key**:

```
Dictionary<string, double> dict = new Dictionary<string, double>();
dict["mamma"] = 123.45;
double d = dict["daddy"]; // throws KeyNotBlarghException
```

dict["daddy"] += 101; // would throw too! tries to read the old/current value!

So, one have to be very careful with it with "keys" that it does not yet know. Fortunatelly, you can always ask the dictionary if it already knows a key:

```
Dictionary<string, double> dict = new Dictionary<string, double>();
dict["mamma"] = 123.45;
bool knowIt = dict.ContainsKey("daddy"); // == false
```

So you can easily check-and-initialize-when-unknown:

```
Dictionary<string, double> dict = new Dictionary<string, double>();
bool knowIt = dict.ContainsKey("daddy"); // == false
if( !knowIt )
    dict["daddy"] = 5;

dict["daddy"] += 101; // now 106
```

So.. let's try summing up the priorities location-wise:

```
Dictionary<string, double> prioSums = new Dictionary<string, double>();
foreach(var row in rows)
{
    string location = (string)rows["LOCATION"];
    double priority  = (double)rows["PRIORITY"];

    if( ! prioSums.ContainsKey(location) )
        // make sure that dictionary knows the location
        prioSums[location] = 0.0;

    prioSums[location] += priority;
}
```

And, really, that's all. Now the `prioSums` will know all locations and all sums of priorities:

```
var sss = prioSums["NewYork"];  // 9123, assuming NewYork was some location
```

However, that'd be quite useless to have to hardcode all locations. Hence, you also can **ask the dictionary about what keys does it curently know**

```
foreach(string key in prioSums.Keys)
    Console.WriteLine(key);
```

and you can immediatelly use it:

```
foreach(string key in prioSums.Keys)
{
    Console.WriteLine(key);
    Console.WriteLine(prioSums[key]);
}
```

that should print all locations with all their sums.

You might already noticed an interesting thing: the dictionary can tell you what keys has it remembered. Hence, you **do not need** the HashSet from the first objective. Simply by summing up the priorities inside the Dictionary, you get the uniquized list of location by free: just ask the dict for its keys.

EDIT:

I noticed you've had a few more requests (like sort-descending or find-highest-prio-value), but I think I'll leave them for now. If you understand how I used a dictionary to collect the priorities, then you will easily build a similar `Dictionary<string,string>` to collect the highest-ranking value for a location. And the 'descending order' is done very easily if only you take the values out of dictionary and sort them as a i.e. List.. So I'll skip that for now.. This text got far tl;dr already I think :)

Comment: Just finished reading your question and, first of all, I just wanna say, in reference to your first paragraph, that you probably misunderstood what I was saying. I have found this question was very hard to articulate all the details of.  Anyway, now that that's out of the way, I just want to say that even though you've helped me very much in the past, you have probably helped me more now than ever. This is exactly the kind of educational answer I was hoping to invoke with my question. I don't say this mainly because of how bad I was stuck or how well your answer fixes my problem...(continued)

Comment: (continued)...but because of the quality of the question, and just how useful it is to my education. I had never even heard of `HashSet`s before and it is nice to know that it is in there inherent nature to omit duplicate values. I had heard of the `Dictionary` list (?) before but knew nothing about it. Honestly, I have only even used lists very rarely. Anytime I see `<` or `>` my brain returns `invalid html tag!` LOL, just kidding, but I am not well versed on lists yet or the `IEnumerable` or how they relate or even if I've used that term correctly, actually...(continued)

Comment: (continued)...Anyway, thank you so much for not just giving me a lump of code to use (*I hate using code I don't understand*). If I don't learn something when I get stuck, than I am setting myself up for a lifetime of being a useless programmer. VERY VERY thankful for your time! (I will try this answer back at work tomorrow. See you then!)

Comment: It seems that even though, yes, I can compile another Dictionary List for the values, I can't really sort two lists together (nor does prioSums have a sort method, at all, actually). I think I might need to try the LINQ answer to see if that better fits the situation. Thanks for teaching me the logic and syntax of the Dictionary and HashSet lists, though!

Comment: Also I tried `prioSums = prioSums.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value).ToList();`, `prioSums = prioSums.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value).ToDictionary();`, `prioSums = prioSums.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value).ToDictionary<string, int>;`, and even just `prioSums = prioSums.OrderByDescending();` but it appears that nothing exists that will allow you to sort a Dictionary list. A huge drawback to be sure, unless I am just not getting the syntax right. I like the Dictionary Lists ability to hold key/value pairs, however, I don't think it will be very useful since it appears it can't sort itself.

Comment: Ultimately, so far, I am still not able to 100% solve my problem with this answer (I am not really even sure it is capable of it, since Dictionaries hold only two values and I need three, one location key, one priority number, and a third highest priority text value).

Comment: LOL, I'm so close but NOTHING works to sort the final order with highest priority first. I looked here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534855.aspx among other places but, nothing works. I don't know what I'm supposed to use for OrderByDescending's arguments. I mean wtf is `<TSource>, Func<TSource, TKey>`? Makes 0 sense that `OrderByDescending` even exists, considering it can't be invoked like a normal method.

Comment: Create two dictionaries: `Dictionary<string|location, double|priority> "prios"` and `Dicitonary<string|location,string|value> "values"`. Iterate over the entries from database: for each entry, get its location and check what priority "prios" remember for it. If none or if worse than current entry, then put current entry's priority into "prios" AND ALSO current entry value into "values". After the loop, in "values" you will have the best values for each location.

Comment: The trick is that "values" for a location gets updated only when "prios" gets updated for that location, and that "prios" are updated only when a new better priority is found for a location. Hence, "Values" will get the "best" value.

Comment: With sorting: Create a class "Item{string value; double priority}". a `Dictionary<string, List<Item>>`. Loop over database entries. For each entry, get its location and fetch the `List<Item>` for it. If not found, create a list and put it to dict immediatelly. Once you have a list for that location, create a new Item with Value and Priority from the databse entry. After the loop you'll have Items grouped in Lists on per-location basis. Now, if you write a IComparer that compares Items only by their Priority, you can Sort each of the Lists and pick the best Value from each first item.

Comment: If you get smart, you can even skip the "class Item" thing and use a `Dictionary<string,DatabaseRow>` ;)

Comment: If you do it that way, this will essentially be the same as if doing "rows.groupby(row.location)" then "grp.Order(row.prorioty).First()" on each grouping. That's why I said that LINQ is usually not magic, but just pretty ;) Don't give up! Write again if you hit on any problems

Comment: Thanks for responding back. As long as you don't give up on me, I won't give up! (can't afford to anyway, lol). So, I see what you mean with the two lists, I guess I was just very afraid that they would end up out of sync when I go to order them, but if they are being ordered as they go, together, all their related values should be on the same index for reference later. However, I'm not sure this is what will happen, and I don't get the need for creating a class here. I thought I knew a bit about C#, but these lists are all so new to me, I don't know if I'll ever get this right.

Comment: On top of that, I will be gone for the first three days of next week (Mon, Tue, Wed) on vacation (1st Anniversary with my amazing wife!) So, you won't hear from me until Thursday (and you WILL hear from me, I assure you I am not quite grasping everything yet). So please don't give up on me yet, I really need this to work! Thanks again for all of your help!

Comment: Okay, so I just got back from vacation and am finally ready to hopefully complete this part of my project. I have two dictionary lists (prioSums and contentVals), and I can compile a clean list of the location (each unique), the priority sums (for all matching locations found), and the values with the highest individual priorities found for each location. The ONLY thing left that I have to do is put them in order from the highest priority sum to the lowest. Hard to do for me since they are in two separate lists. It has been a while since I have created a non-static class and will have to...

Comment: ...toy around with it to get it just right probably. Either way, though, I am not sure the logic I should use. Also, I have no idea what an `IComparer` is. What should I start with?

Comment: Hello again. Sorry for the delay, I've had many things to do in RL.

Comment: I hope you are still "within subject" and remember what you have achieved and how you did it. Now, you probably have a few Dictionaries and/or Hashsets, and all of them are simple-valued like `<string>` or `<double>`. Ok. So, shortly, let's look at nonstatic classes. Look at i.e. the `<string>`. What is it? I mean, what is a string? Probably, you'd say "a class" or "an object", or "a data/value". Well. In fact, all of them. That's because my question was ill-constructed. There is a "string class", there are "string objects" and there are "string data/values". Note the counts.

Comment: Looking at it very simply, a "class" is a code-thing that defines what is the shape of the data, and what operations/functions/methods you can invoke/run/execute on it.

Comment: The "string data/values" are just a pack of byte that contains the interesting information. In this example, string-like information. So, it could be a null-terminated C-string, or len/data Pascal encoding. But, that would be just a properly formatted pack of bytes with data.

Comment: The "object" is different from "class" and "data". Typically and somewhat traditionally, an object consists of two things: some "data" and a link to "class". Note that it does not necessarily be a literal meaning. Just the notion is important.

Comment: So, in string example, you have a string-class (somewhere in the .Net Framework code), that defines methods of the strings. Also, that class defines the shape of the data package. ## Then, when your program is running, you've got many string-objects in the memory. Each of them depicts or wraps some data: "mom", "dog". Each of them is related to a separate data, but all of them link to the same string-class. Hence, whenever you have a string-object at hand, you know what methods you can call on it. And all string have the same methods and behavior, just on different data.

Comment: String-values are hidden. They are hidden somewhere behind the objects. If you'd program in C/C++ class language, you'd probably be able to see them if you scanned the memory corresponding to an object, but here it is not necessary.

Comment: In code, when you create "class XYZ { blahblah }", you define a class. But you do it at "namespace level", not in a method or a loop.

Comment: When you write ` new XYZ() `, you create a new object of XYZ class. It will be shaped just like the XYZ class described. It will contain all fields/properties/methods that class defined. And it will have its own "identity". Just like two different strings(*-note), two new objects are naturally different.

Comment: `var one = new XYZ(); one.field = 5;    var two = new XYZ(); two.field = 1234;` - will create two objects: one will remember that its field is 5, the second that its the **same field** is 1234. `Console.WriteLine(one.field); Console.WriteLine(two.field);` will give 5 and 1234. Despite it being "the same field" of "the same class", it was set&stored in/on "different objects".

Comment: This is absolutely normal if you think about the objects as a "furniture from IKEA" or any other carpentry-related market in your country. A "class" is the designpaper of a bookshelf. An "object" is the bookshelf itself. You can have many. The "data" is the exact 130page book that you've put into one of the shelves.

Comment: In the above example you've got: one designpaper called "XYZ", two bookshelves: first called "one" and second called "two", and two books one with 5 pages put into bookshelf "one", and second 1234pages put into bookshelf "two".

Comment: Ok, if you know&feel it then sorry, but my lenghy introduction has just one point: that describes normal classes/objects/data, not **static** ones as you probably noticed. Note that I say "normal". The  "static" ones are not normal. They are odd, different, wicked, .. oh, I think I've got the best word: **distorted**.

Comment: A "static class" is a class, a designpaper, that **does not allow** you to create an object. Not a single one. Zero. Absolutely none. What "designpaper" it is then? Strange one. It describes a bookself, but instead of allowing you to create a real bookshelf and put a book into it -- that distorted designpaper allows you to **put the book directly into the designpaper**. Whoa.

Comment: So, with normal ones with objects, you'd need to give the bookshelf to somebody, so somebody can then get the bookshelf, look at its designpaper to know its structure, and then he'd know how to read the book from that shelf. With statics, there's just the magical designpaper: you put there a book, and your friend looks at the designpaper and already sees the book with out any bookshelf.

Comment: "classes/designpapers" are just "magically known", while "objects/bookshelves" are well, "items" that can be passed around, given, stored, taken, sent, received etc.

Comment: Back to the code: `Dictionary<string, double>`. It represents a structure where you "link" a "double" to a "string". A "number object" to a "string object". Not class, not data.

Comment: Hence, you can have, for example, a `Dictionary<string, XYZ>` too, or `Dictionary<XYZ, double>` or whatever combination you like.

Comment: Mind the power: XYZ class describes a shape of a bookshelf. Dictionary allows you to either link a bookshelf-to-a-string `Dictionary<string,XYZ>` (think about it as loose catalogue saying "comedy books"->"are standing there"), or a "string-to-a-bookshelf" `Dictionary<XYZ, string>" (think about a yellow triangular plate nailed to a bookshelf, saying "comedy"), or even, can link bookshelf-to-a-bookshelf (uh, imagine a tiny microscope-level bookshelf nailed to a side of a big bookshelf..). The "nail" is a bit bad choice, but I think you are fluent with dictionaries far by now

Comment: Anyways, XYZ is defined just whatever you like. It's your design, it may contain many fields. Let's say `class XYZ{ int x, int y, double weight, string name }`. Sorry for the syntax, but that's somewhat irrelevant. Here, a `Dictionary<string, XYZ>` would allow you to link a `x=5, y=123, weight=44.5, name="Jumbo"` to a string "LosAngeles", and also a `x=-3, y=33, weight=0.5, name="Tinkerbell"` to a "tree". So that `var visitor = dict["Tree"]; visitor.Name == 'Tinkerbell'`.

Comment: going back: Your problem was: you've got your data cleanly and properly calculated, but they were in `two separate lists`. With objects, you can **group the data into packages of arbitrary shapes**.

Comment: You've got:  `list of unique locations`, `dictio location -> sum of prios`, and `dictio location -> highestranked value`. Look at their shape closely.

Comment: Note that the two dictios have the same key: a location. So, in fact, the data they contain is similarly packetized. sum-per location, bestvalue per location. So why not just {sumPrio, bestValue} per location?

Comment: Define: `class XYZ { double prios; string bestvalue; }` and now you can `Dictionary<string, XYZ> dict` and you can.. `dict["page55"].bestvalue = "mom"; dict["page55"].prios = 53.21;`

Comment: Of course, everything gets little complicated. Before touching it you still have to check if the entry exists and initialize the entry so it is known. Now, not with "0" or "string", but with "object of XYZ": `if(!dict.ContainsKey(kkk))  dict[kkk] = new XYZ();`. Well, not that complicated actually.

Comment: That way, you can build up a set of {prios, bestvals} for each location. You don't need two. What's more, small side note: Do you remember how you calculated "highest ranked value" for a location? In a loop, you've overwritten "previos best value" with "a better value" for a location. `dictio[place] = bettervalue`. Executing it many times for the same place did not result in having many "page34"s with different values. Dictionaries hold unique keys, and you can always as the dictionary about what keys does it know:  `var allkeys = diction.Keys;`.

Comment: (Sidenote continued): This means that if you built the dictionary, you don't need the "list of unique names". The dictionary provides it: `var names = dictio.Keys;  var page1prio = dictio["page1"].prios;  var page1val = dictio["page1"].bestvalue;` (sidenote end)

Comment: So, you've got a dictio that knows-it-all. How to sort it? Well, you can't directly. Dictionary is unsorted by default, so it can order the items internally for the quickest lookup. But, you can ask the dictio to give you all the values: `var allvalues = dictio.Values;` similarly to how you read the keys. Those 'values' will be the exactly the same "XYZ objects" that you've put there first. But how to sort them?

Comment: Framework knows what is the "normal order" of a set of standard integers/dobles/strings, so it can sort them. But with your custom XYZ class..? How the framework may know whether {prio=5, value="dad"} is better than {prio=25, value="mom"}? Here's where `IComparer` shows up: it is a thing that knows how to compare two objects, and the sorting mechanism will ask it to compare your objects to determine the proper order. MSDN: Simple sorting: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bzw8611x.aspx More complex IComparer:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf.aspx

Comment: Look at the complex one: see how it compares two Boxes? We need a comparer that will compare two XYZs with respect to the order you now want!

Comment: Then, let's get back to our know-it-all dictio. Get the Value of it. Put them into an Array. Create a new comparer object (`var cmp = new MyXYZComparer()`), and call the Array.Sort method: `Array.Sort(arrWithValues, cmp)` and you array of values will get sorted according to the "lesser/greater" definition provided by the comparer. Loop through the array and print out all the prios/bestvalues.

Comment: Ahem. Ok. So we've just got our values sorted properly, but that's only prios and values.. Where are "locations"?

Comment: Locations were left at know-it-all dictionary. They were the keys. We asked the dictionary about its Values. Right? So no wonder that names/keys are missing.

Comment: Now we've got a ton of options on how to fix it. I'll drop you the easiest: redefine. You have total control on how the XYZ item looks like, so total control over the shape dictionary's Values. Add a location name to it! `class XYZ { double prios; string bestvalue; string locationname;}` and of course **remember to SET it**: `if (! dict.ContainsKey(kkk)) { var newitem = new XYZ(); newitem.locationname=kkk; dictio[kkk] = newitem; }` and that's all.

Comment: Now your "Values" of a Dictionary contain all relevant information: the (calculated)sumofprios, the (calculated)bestvalue and the locationname that neverchanges and is always equal to its own Key, so after sorting it with Sort/Comparer, you'll be able now print out everything.

Comment: So, to sum up: (1) create a class that will describe the Item of your dictionary that will hold some information-per-location. (2) create the dictio location->items (3) use that dictio (and maybe some other helper lists/dictios) to store the results of "finding sumOfPrios" and "finding bestValues" (4) get items out of dictio and sort them -- which requires you to write a Comparer that says what is "greater" and what is "less", so the sorting may happen.

Comment: Last thing.. I've left a (*) far above when I talked about string and "beig different". Strings are khem, heh, special. .Net/C# tried to make them much like numbers. 5 is == to a 5, so a "mom" is == "mom" even if they are possibly different objects. I'll not delve into the string pooling and etc, but the point is that if you compar'=='e strings **as strings** `string a = "mom"; string b = textbox.Text"; if ( b == a ) { ... }`, then "mom" from textbox will always equal to "mom". No suprise probably. Due to the "string a" and "string b" you will never notice those strings are different objects.

Comment: But, if you really compare them as **objects**: `object a = "mom"; object  b = textbox.Text"; if ( b == a ) { ... }` this will probably always fail: the compiled "mom" value will turn out to be different that a "mom" entered by textbox. The textbox read the text from the UI and constructed a `new string()` and set its data to "mom". But, it's a `new object`! not the same that you've set to the 'a' variable by setting it to "mom" text. This is normal object behaviour. The earlier case when `string a=mom; string b = ..` was distorted/magic because compiler **knew** that a/b are strings

Comment: ..and silently changed meaning of `==` operator so that "better comparison" was used. OTOH, with `object a, obejct b` comiler can't, since theoretically 'a' and 'b' can be anything, even 5, 3.6 or a `dictionary<>`, and it just-happens that you set them to strings..  Try: `object a = "mom"; object b = textbox.Text"; if ( b.Equals(a) ) { ... }` and it now will turn up that "mom" is equal to "mom" again. It's because the string has overriden the Equals method so that it compares values to make handy comparisons. Any objects that does not override it are != by default, unless are the same object.

Comment: I'm sorry I've bloated the text so much, but since you've hardly used "normal classes/objects", I was not sure if and which terms/ideas/concepts you had right and which - not. I hope that everything will be clear after you play with the examples a little. If not, feel free to ask. I'll try to be more brief next time :P

Comment: Hey there, sorry for the delay, myself. I just moved desks recently and haven't had Internet at work for a while. I will read over what you've added very soon. Also, I am very grateful for your descriptive response. As long as SO doesn't mind this many comments, I know I sure don't. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

LINQ is really the tool to use for this kind of problems.

Suppose you have a variable `pages` which is an `IEnumerable<Page>`, where `Page` is a class with properties `location`, `priority` and `value` you could do

```
var query = from page in pages
    group page by page.location into grp
    select new { location = grp.Key,
                 priority = grp.Sum(page => page.priority),
                 value = grp.OrderByDescending(page => page.priority)
                            .First().value
               }
```

You say you don't understand LINQ, so let me try to *begin* explain this statement.

The rows are group by `location`, which results in 4 groups of pages of which `page.location` is the key:

```
location  priority  value  
--------------------------------------
page1     1         some text!
page2     3         more text!
          4         even more text!
page3     1         text
          1         still more text!
          3         text again
page4     6         text
```

The `select` loops through these 4 groups and for each group it creates an anonymous type with 3 properties:

1. `location`: the key of the group
2. `priority`: the sum of priorities in one group
3. `value`: the first `value` in one group when its pages are sorted by priority in descending order.

The lamba expressions are a way to express which property should be used for a LINQ function like `Sum`. In short they say "transform `page` to `page.priority`": `page => page.priority`.

You want these new rows in descending order of priority, so finally you can do

```
result = query.OrderByDescending(x => x.priority).ToList();
```

The `x` is just an arbitrary placeholder representing one item in the collection in hand, `query` (likewise in the query above `page` could have been any word or character).

Comment: Man, I am so happy that my question provoked the two different approaches that it did! I have learned A LOT from your answer on LINQ and thank you for finally explaining to me the non-text-version of what the lambda expression was. I think I feel like I am finally beginning to understand them now. I think the only thing I am still a little confused about is the exact logic behind `in grp` here. Are you naming the table (for lack of a better word) here? Also, where exactly does the `result = query.OrderByDescending( x => x.priority).ToList();` go? Sorry, still trying to put this together.

Comment: `grp` is a name (again arbitrary) that needs to be given to a group of pages for further porcessing (by the way, I made a small syntax error - edited). The `result` vould go right after the first statement.

Comment: @VoidKing: actually, what I suggested is not that different than what you can do with LINQ. The LINQ-way has just the loops removed and hidden somewhere in LINQ queries and operators ;) It might not be obvious at first glance, but its another story. If you have some time, please try solving your problem tree times: once in "classic" way, once with LINQ like Gert presented, and then try also with LINQ but without "linq syntax", so instead of "from x in pages / group .. " try to use "pages.GroupBy(..". It can give you a different point of view on LINQ, but - it's not easy and heavy on lambdas.

Comment: Okay, well I get an error with the very first thing I try to do here. If I use 'IEnumerable<Page> page = new IEnumerable<Page>();', then I get this error: `Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Web.UI.Page>'` Well, that attempt didn't last very long, LOL, perhaps you could clarify how I am supposed to create the `page` variable in the first place. Do ***I*** need to create the class? If so, why does Intellisense recognize `<Page>` as a viable argument for `IEnumerable`? Well, back to try the first answer again.

Comment: You should use a `Page` class of your own make. Not any .Net class named `Page`.

Comment: I created a class, but now I get a syntax error on the first line that says `pages does not exist in the current context` hmmmmm.... It seems even with good advice I am not able to do this. Why does C# have to have so many confusing list types, when really all they need is to be able to make arrays more dynamic (like JavaScript for example) and cut this `IEnumerable` nonsense out. The fact that you have to set the dimensions of an array when declared (forcing you to use lists) is just under par with other programming languages. What I really need is a 3 dimension array, but needs to be dynamic

Comment: I think you're ready for a new question how to create an `IEnumerable<T>` from a query. You never need to worry about arrays and sizes if you use collections of classes.