# What's the easiest way to reorder two dictionary lists together in C#?

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, webmatrix, asp.net-webpages

**BACKGROUND TO THE PROBLEM**

Say I had the following two lists (prioSums and contentVals) compiled from a SQL Server CE query like this:

```
var queryResults = db.Query(searchQueryString, searchTermsArray);

Dictionary<string, double> prioSums = new Dictionary<string, double>();
Dictionary<string, string> contentVals = new Dictionary<string, string>();
double prioTemp = 0.0;
foreach(var row in queryResults)
{
    string location = row.location;
    double priority = row.priority;

    if (!prioSums.ContainsKey(location))
    {
        prioSums[location] = 0.0;
    }

    if (!contentVals.ContainsKey(location))
    {
        contentVals[location] = row.value;
        prioTemp = priority;
    }

    if (prioTemp < priority)
    {
        contentVals[location] = row.value;
    }

    prioSums[location] += priority;
}
```

The query itself is pretty large, very dynamically compiled, and really beyond the scope of this question, so I'll just say that it returns rows that include a priority, text value, and location.

With the above code I am able to get one list (prioSums) which sums up all of the priorities for each location (not allowing repeats on the location [key] itself, even though repeats for the location are in the query results), and another list (contentVals) to hold the value of the location with the highest priority, once again, using the location as key.

All of this I have accomplished and it works very well. I can iterate over the two lists and display the information I want HOWEVER...

**THE PROBLEM**

...Now I need to reorder these lists together with the highest priority (or sums of priorities which are stored as the values in prioSums) first.

I have wracked my brain trying to think about using an instantiated class with three properties as given advice by others, but I can't seem to wrap my brain on how that would work, given my WebMatrix C#.net-webpages environment. I know how to call a class from a `.cs` file from the current `.cshtml` file, no problem, but I have never done this by instantiating a class to make it an object before (sorry, still new to some of the more complex C# logic/methodology).

Can anyone suggest how to accomplish this, or perhaps show an easier (at least easier to understand) way of doing this? In short all I really need is these two lists ordered together by the value in prioSums from highest to lowest.

**NOTE**

Please forgive me if I have not provided quite enough information. If more should be provided don't hesitate to ask.

Also, for more information or background on this problem, you can look at my previous question on this here: [Is there any way to loop through my sql results and store certain name/value pairs elsewhere in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17604201/is-there-any-way-to-loop-through-my-sql-results-and-store-certain-name-value-pai)

Comment: its not that clear,1 list with priority and location,and second with value and location?

Comment: And the new set? dictionary<double,string> (double is the priority and string the value like in contentvals)?

Comment: @terrybozzio Sorry about the clarity issue just look at the link below for more information as this was a question I asked some days ago that leads right up to this point. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17604201/is-there-any-way-to-loop-through-my-sql-results-and-store-certain-name-value-pai

Comment: @terrybozzio Ultimately I will need three things for each 'item': 1) a location 2) the sum of all priorities found for all of the locations returned from the query (locations won't repeat in the lists) and 3) a text value for the location where this value returned from the query had the highest individual priority among results from the query. HOWEVER, it may not be necessary to know all of this. All that you need to know (I think) is that I have two lists. Each list uses the locations as the keys and one list has the priority sums as a value and the other has the text value as the list value.

Comment: @terrybozzio And honestly, I already have that in and of itself. What I need is to reorder these two lists together with the highest value of prioSums first.

Comment: A sorteddictionary<double,string>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know if its the outcome you want but you can give it a try:

```
var result = from p in prioSums
          orderby p.Value descending
          select new { location = p.Key, priority = p.Value, value = contentVals[p.Key] };
```

Comment: How would I access the three values later? Sorry I am very new to LINQ

Comment: Also, what is this creating? That is, what is being created with the line `select new { location = p.Key, priority = p.Value, value = contentVals[p.Key]` This seems an intelligent answer, as I can see how all are getting accessed, but I'm just not sure where the new ordered values are being stored for reference later. I suppose looping through the results and displaying them one at a time (instead of storing them in a separate location) might work, too.

Comment: Holy freakin' underwear! I think I just got this to work on the first try. I used this just after the code you provided above to simply display the results on the page: `foreach (var doodad in result)
            {
                @doodad.location <text>||</text> @doodad.priority <text>||</text> @doodad.value <br/>
            }` and it seems to totally be working. I take it that result becomes an object with 3 properties? Did I do this right?

Comment: sorry was away...result will be a "list"(a "whereselectenumerableiterator"),its created with the anonymous types inside,where in your loop each item is "doodad",meaning result becomes a list with n objects(in your case "doodad"),each with the 3 properties you needed.